# Explode Array values

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5.4

Please help me to resolve the issue found at the below cases as follows:

I want a result like this

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    0 => "Dashboard,Employee,Lead"
  ]
]
```

From this

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    0 => "0,4,5"
  ]
]
```

I want a value as name not an id

This is my code

```
public function boot()
{
    view()->composer('admin.sidebar', function ($view) {
        $moduleRs = DB::table('users')
        ->join('permissions','users.role', '=', 'permissions.role_id') 
        ->select('users.role as usersrole','permissions.role_id as 
           role_id','permissions.module_name as module_name')
        ->where('users.role', '=', \Auth::user()->role)
        ->get();
       // dd($moduleRs[0]->module_name);
        $moduleData = null;
```

This is the condition checks

```
if ( count($moduleRs) > 0 ) {
    $result = [];
    foreach($moduleRs as $row){
        if(!isset($result[$row->role_id])) {
            $result[$row->role_id] = array(
                'role_id' => $row->role_id,
                'module_name' => [$row->module_name],
        );
        }else{
            $result[$row->role_id]['module_name'] = array_merge($result[$row->role_id]['module_name'], [$row->module_name] );
        } 
}
```

Array explode functions

```
$data=$moduleRs[0]->module_name;
$splittedstring[] = explode(" ,",$data);
//dd($splittedstring); 

foreach ($splittedstring as $key => $value) {
    echo "  '.$value.'<br>";
}  
}    

$view->with('moduleData', $moduleData);
});

}
```

Comment: What does this returns 'module_name' => [$row->module_name], have you checked?

Comment: Ya this will return id..sorry module_name is not a string datatype its a integer value in database. Table name=>module,field name=>modules[Dashboard,Roles,Permissions,Employee,Lead] fetching this table values and stores in a table..Table name=>permissions,field name=>module_name(id of module table's module field name)

Answer (score 0):

Your query seems perfect to me.

Check the result of `'module_name' => [$row->module_name],` because it may be `Int` data type.

Comment: It will returns 0,4,5 as array values.please dont confuse module_name is not a string lets u consider module_name as module_id